# how to get value from a different string (python)

Tags: python

How to make user to type diameter and it prints the value?

```
import random

class Coin:

    def __init__(self, rare=False, clean=True, heads=True, **sparta):

        for key, value in sparta.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

        if self.is_rare:
            self.value = self.original_value * 1.25
        else:
            self.value = self.original_value

    def __del__(self):
        print("Coin spent!")


class fiftycent(Coin):
    def __init__(self):
        data = {
            "original_value": 0.50,
            "diameter": 2.27,

        }

        super().__init__(**data)


class Twentycent(Coin):
    def __init__(self):
        data = {
            "original_value": 0.20,
            "diameter": 2.06,
        }

        super().__init__(**data)


class tencent(Coin):
    def __init__(self):
        data = {
            "original_value": 0.10,
            "diameter": 1.88,
        }

        super().__init__(**data)
```

It should be easy but im not a IT student so im kinda stuck.

Comment: What's your expected input/output? By "user to type diameter" it sounds like you want this to run on the command line but but I don't see any way of the user doing so.

Comment: actually its a coin machine, the machine have to detect the value of the coin according to diameter as user drops it

Comment: Ok, so is this a proof of concept? If not, there's a big chunk of code missing that determines where you're getting that information from

Comment: yeah, its just a proof of concept

Comment: Brings me back to my original question, I assume by input you mean a user typing in something, in which you need to get said input via the function of the same name.

Comment: The user will drop a coin and the machine have to detect the value. Im not sure if its possible to do that, thats why I changed it to user input the diameter and the output will be the value

Comment: is it possible fro machines to detect it by diameter?

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of ways that you could build logic around the classes you've defined to get to the result you're asking for. The main thing is that you have to actually create an instance of each coin before you can do anything with them.  Once you've done that, you want to be able to find each coin by its diameter.

So maybe you want to create an instance of each coin and put each instance in an index that allows access to each coin by its diameter.  Here's code that does that:

```
import random

class Coin:

    def __init__(self, rare=False, clean=True, heads=True, **sparta):

        for key, value in sparta.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

        if rare:
            self.value = self.original_value * 1.25
        else:
            self.value = self.original_value

    def __del__(self):
        pass
#        print("Coin spent!")


class Fiftycent(Coin):
    def __init__(self):
        data = {
            "original_value": 0.50,
            "diameter": 2.27,

        }

        super().__init__(**data)


class Twentycent(Coin):
    def __init__(self):
        data = {
            "original_value": 0.20,
            "diameter": 2.06,
        }

        super().__init__(**data)


class Tencent(Coin):
    def __init__(self):
        data = {
            "original_value": 0.10,
            "diameter": 1.88,
        }

        super().__init__(**data)

# index that allows lookup of coin by diameter
coins = {}

# add a coin to the index
def add_coin(coin):
    coins[coin.diameter] = coin

# add each of our coin types to the index
add_coin(Fiftycent())
add_coin(Twentycent())
add_coin(Tencent())

# get user input of diameter
diameter = float(input("Enter a diameter: "))

# if our index has an entry for the entered diameter, print the value, else
# complain that we don't recognize the entered diameter.
if diameter not in coins:
    print("Unknown coin")
else:
    print("Value: " + str(coins[diameter].value))
```

Sample run:

```
Enter a diameter: 2.27
Value: 0.5
```

Note that I had to change a few lines of your code that were incorrect.  I also made your class names consistently start with uppercase letters, which is the way things should be.  If this were real production code, you'd want to check to make sure the user entered a valid number, but I'll leave that to you to add to this code.

Comment: aight got it, but is it possible to alter this code for coin machine? if not, what else are needed?

Comment: Of course it is.  You can alter the code to do anything you want.  "What else is needed" is for you to figure out.  That's what being a programmer is all about.  If you're going to have someone else write all your code for you, why are you taking the time to do this at all?  If this is for a class, then why are you taking the class, if not because you want to know how to do this stuff yourself?